# How can i create an XML for dynamic tabsheet in delphi

Tags: xml, delphi

I created a dynamic `TTabSheet` in a `TPageControl`, which creates `TLabelEdit` and host related data from an INI file. I created XML for static components but I don't know how to create my XML format for it.

```pascal
AnzahlPositinen := INIDatei.ReadInteger('POS','AnzPos', 1);
for i := 1 to AnzahlPositinen do
begin
  NeueSeite := TTabSheet.Create(PC_Positionen);
  NeueSeite.PageControl := PC_Positionen;
  NeueSeite.Caption := 'Position ' + IntToStr(i);

  MeinEdit := TLabeledEdit.Create(NeueSeite);
  MeinEdit.Left := 10;
  MeinEdit.Top  := 20;
  MeinEdit.Name := 'Artikelnummer' +IntToStr(i);
  MeinEdit.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('POS', '00' + IntToStr(i) +  'BT-153','');
  MeinEdit.EditLabel.Caption := 'Artikelnummer';
  MeinEdit.Width := 175;
  MeinEdit.LabelPosition := lpAbove;
  MeinEdit.Parent := NeueSeite;

  MeinEdit := TLabeledEdit.Create(NeueSeite);
  MeinEdit.Left := 10;
  MeinEdit.Top  := 60;
  MeinEdit.Name := 'Artikelbeschreibung' +IntToStr(i);
  MeinEdit.Text := INIDatei.ReadString('POS', '00' + IntToStr(i) +  'BT-154','');
  MeinEdit.EditLabel.Caption := 'Artikelbeschreibung';
  MeinEdit.Width := NeueSeite.Width -20;
  MeinEdit.LabelPosition := lpAbove;
  MeinEdit.Parent := NeueSeite;
```

When this part is created dynamically, regarding to my Position number, which is (3) in this example, it should create XML with this format:

```xml
 <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="KGM">411.04</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">1561.95</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Description>Stahlwechsel, grundiert (F0)</cbc:Description>
      <cbc:Name>Stahlwechsel, grundiert (Flachstahl) Netto- nicht rabattierfähig.</cbc:Name>
      <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID>40</cbc:ID>
      </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
      <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Percent>19</cbc:Percent>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
    </cac:Item>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="EUR">3.8</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</ubl:Invoice>
```

The text should come from the `TLabelEdit` which I created in my dynamic `TTabSheet`!

I can create XML with normal text from an existing `TestEdit.Text`, for example, but when I want to get text from my `for` loop, it doesn't return any value!

this is how i create all my xml

```
procedure TDlg_XRechnung.XML_erstellen;
var xRoot : IXMLNode;
  i, a: Integer;
begin
  X_Rechnung.XML.Clear;
  X_Rechnung.Active := True;
  X_Rechnung.Version := '1.0';
  X_Rechnung.StandAlone := 'yes';
  X_Rechnung.Encoding := 'UTF-8'; //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  X_Rechnung.Options := [doNodeAutoCreate, doNodeAutoIndent, doAttrNull];
  xRoot := X_Rechnung.AddChild('ubl:Invoice');
  xRoot.DeclareNamespace('ubl','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2');
  xRoot.DeclareNamespace('cac','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2');
  xRoot.DeclareNamespace('cbc','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2');
//  if _Version = XRechnungVersion_122 then
//  begin
//    xRoot.DeclareNamespace('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
//    xRoot.Attributes['xsi:schemaLocation'] := 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd';
//    xRoot.AddChild('cbc:CustomizationID').Text := 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_1.2';
//  end else
//  begin
//    xRoot.AddChild('cbc:CustomizationID').Text := 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_2.0'+
//         IfThen(InternalExtensionEnabled,'#conformant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:extension:xrechnung_2.0','');
//  end;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsnummer.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:IssueDate').Text := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Edit_Rechnungsdatum.Date);
  if Edit_Leistungsdatum.Date > 100 then xRoot.AddChild('cbc:DueDate').Text := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Edit_Leistungsdatum.Date);
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:InvoiceTypeCode').Text := '380'; // die verschiedenen Codes aus function
  if Trim(Edit_Bemerkung.Text) <> '' then xRoot.AddChild('cbc:Note').Text := Edit_Bemerkung.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode').Text := Edit_Waehrung_Rechnung.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:TaxCurrencyCode').Text := Edit_Waehrung_UST.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:BuyerReference').Text := '';
//  if (_Invoice.InvoicePeriodStartDate > 100) and (_Invoice.InvoicePeriodEndDate > 100) then
//  with xRoot.AddChild('cac:InvoicePeriod') do
//  begin
//    AddChild('cbc:StartDate').Text := TXRechnungHelper.DateToStrUBLFormat(_Invoice.InvoicePeriodStartDate);
//    AddChild('cbc:EndDate').Text := TXRechnungHelper.DateToStrUBLFormat(_Invoice.InvoicePeriodEndDate);
//  end;
  if Trim(Edit_Bestellnummer.Text) <> '' then
    xRoot.AddChild('cac:OrderReference').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := Edit_Bestellnummer.Text
  else
    xRoot.AddChild('cac:OrderReference').Text := '';

  with xRoot.AddChild('cac:AccountingSupplierParty').AddChild('cac:Party') do
  begin
    with AddChild('cac:PartyIdentification') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyName') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Name.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PostalAddress') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:StreetName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Adresse.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:AdditionalStreetName').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName;
      AddChild('cbc:CityName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Ort.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:PostalZone').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_PLZ.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:CountrySubentity').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine <> '' then
//        AddChild('cac:AddressLine').AddChild('cbc:Line').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine;
      AddChild('cac:Country').AddChild('cbc:IdentificationCode').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Land.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyTaxScheme') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_UST_ID.Text;
      AddChild('cac:TaxScheme').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := 'VAT';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyLegalEntity') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:RegistrationName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Name.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Firmenbuch.Text;
    end;
//    with AddChild('cac:Contact') do
//    begin
//      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.ContactName;
//      AddChild('cbc:Telephone').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.ContactTelephone;
//      AddChild('cbc:ElectronicMail').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.ContactElectronicMail;
//    end;
  end;
  with xRoot.AddChild('cac:AccountingCustomerParty').AddChild('cac:Party') do
  begin
    with AddChild('cac:PartyIdentification') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyName') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PostalAddress') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:StreetName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Adresse.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:AdditionalStreetName').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName;
      AddChild('cbc:CityName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Ort.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:PostalZone').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_PLZ.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:CountrySubentity').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine <> '' then
//        AddChild('cac:AddressLine').AddChild('cbc:Line').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine;
      AddChild('cac:Country').AddChild('cbc:IdentificationCode').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Land.Text;
    end;
     with AddChild('cac:PartyTaxScheme') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID');
      AddChild('cac:TaxScheme').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := 'VAT';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyLegalEntity') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:RegistrationName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text;
      //AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Firmenbuch.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:Contact') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name');
      AddChild('cbc:Telephone');
      AddChild('cbc:ElectronicMail');
    end;
  end;

  ShowMessage(TLabeledEdit(Self.FindComponent('Artikelbeschreibung1')).Text);

  for i := 1 to PC_Positionen.PageCount do
  begin
    for a := 0 to PC_Positionen.ControlCount -1 do
    begin
      if PC_Positionen.Controls[a].Name = 'Artikelbeschreibung' +IntToStr(i) then
      begin
        if PC_Positionen.Controls[a] is TLabeledEdit then
        begin

          with xRoot.AddChild('cac:InvoiceLine') do
          begin
            AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := TLabeledEdit(PC_Positionen.Controls[a]).Text;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;


//    with AddChild('cbc:InvoicedQuantity') do
//    begin
//        Attributes['unitCode'] := 'M2';
//        Text := Edit1test.Text;
//      end;
//    with AddChild('cbc:LineExtensionAmount') do
//      begin
//        Attributes['currencyID'] := Edit_Waehrung_UST.Text;
//        Text := Edit1test.Text;
//      end;
//    with AddChild('cac:Item') do
//      begin
//        AddChild('cbc:Description').Text := '';
//        AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := '';
//        AddChild('cac:SellersItemIdentification').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text :='';
//        with AddChild('cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory') do
//        begin
//          AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '';
//          AddChild('cbc:Percent').Text := '';
//          AddChild('cac:TaxScheme').AddChild('cbc:ID');
//        end;
//
//      end;
//    with AddChild('cac:Price')do
//      begin
//        with AddChild('cbc:PriceAmount') do
//        begin
//          Attributes['currencyID'] := Edit_Waehrung_UST.Text ;
//          Text := Edit1test.Text ;
//        end;
//
//      end;
//    end;
  end;
```

and this is where i have problem

```
  for i := 1 to PC_Positionen.PageCount do
  begin
    for a := 0 to PC_Positionen.ControlCount -1 do
    begin
      if PC_Positionen.Controls[a].Name = 'Artikelbeschreibung' +IntToStr(i) then
      begin
        if PC_Positionen.Controls[a] is TLabeledEdit then
        begin

          with xRoot.AddChild('cac:InvoiceLine') do
          begin
            AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := TLabeledEdit(PC_Positionen.Controls[a]).Text;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you are having trouble with when creating the XML.

Comment: Thanks!i provided

Comment: Is your real question "How to iterate over all controls in each page of a `TPageControl`?" If so, you need `for i := 0 to PageControl1.PageCount - 1 do
    for j := 0 to PageControl1.Pages[i].ControlCount - 1 do
      if PageControl1.Pages[i].Controls[j] is TLabel then
        ShowMessage(TLabel(PageControl1.Pages[i].Controls[j]).Caption);`

Comment: Thanks ! I will try it but I just used showmessage to see do i have  any return or not ! It’s not a part of my XML!

Comment: @maxfido: I didn't even know you had a `ShowMessage` in your code; I didn't read it that carefully. My guess is that your real Q has nothing to do with XML but is only about how to iterate all ctls on all sheets of a page control, and my snippet above illustrates this using `TLabel` controls and `ShowMessage` as an example.

Comment: @maxfido look more carefully at your loop, and then look at the loop that Andreas gave you. You are not looping through the child controls of the TabSheets at all, you are looping through the child controls of the PageControl instead. Two different things

Comment: Why did you post lines and lines of commented out code? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem you're having - pay attention to the **minimal** in that phrase. Don't include noise like commented out code; post the **bare minimum amount of code** necessary.